# Dynamic column change in where clause

Tags: sql, plsql

Below is the my source and target data.

```
Source
ename   eno dept
    A   1   Rcl
    A   2   Ecs

Reference
ename   eno dept    sal hike
    A   1            10 5%
    A       Ecs      20 2%

Target
ename   eno dept    sal hike
    A   1   Rcl      10 5%
    A   2   Ecs      20 2%
```

I have to do column comparison on based on reference cloumn nullability.

Exampl

for my first record reference ename and eno are not null,

my condition will be

```
select a.ename,b.sal,b.hike
from source a, ref_table b
where a.ename=b.ename
  and a.eno=b.en0
```

for second record in my ref_table ename and dept column are not null, so my logic wolud be

```
select a.ename,b.sal,b.hike
from source a, ref_table b
where a.ename=b.ename
  and a.dept=b.dept
```

my where has change on runttim . can you please provide your valable solutions on my requirement.

Comment: Ah, fall - when institutions of higher learning fling open their doors to welcome a new crop of students who, eager to expand their horizons, post their homework on StackOverflow and then slope off to the nearest pub, confident that their assignments will soon be completed without them having to expend actual effort. They'll be gone by mid-winter, sent back to hearth and home by professorial admonition in the form of failing grades (for if someone else does the assignment, what does the student learn?) but it's nice to see that the circle still turns and time marches on. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be as simple as this:

```
SELECT  a.ename,b.sal,b.hike
FROM source a, ref_table b
where 
(b.ename IS NOT NULL AND b.eno IS NOT NULL AND
 a.ename=b.ename AND a.eno=b.eno)
OR 
(b.ename IS NOT NULL AND b.dept IS NOT NULL AND
  a.ename=b.ename AND a.dept=b.dept)
```

This can be reduced to this:

```
SELECT  a.ename,b.sal,b.hike
FROM source a, ref_table b
where a.ename=b.ename
AND ((b.eno IS NOT NULL AND a.eno=b.eno)
  OR (b.dept IS NOT NULL AND a.dept=b.dept)
```

For the case when you have several columns that can have NULL, try solution with default value that equals to value from other table:

```
SELECT  a.ename,b.sal,b.hike
FROM source a, ref_table b
WHERE a.ename = NVL(b.ename, a.ename)
 AND a.eno = NVL(b.eno, a.eno)
 AND a.dept = NVL(b.dept, a.dept)
```

This way NULL values will be ignored in your WHERE clause.

Comment: actually I mentioned my requirement with only three fields...the comparison cloumns will be 7 or more and in that seven fields any two or three or four or five or six etc.... are not null in different combination . my logic has to check not null fields of ref_table and compare with those fields with source data.

Comment: please update your question, I don't really get what will be 7, 2, 3, 5, 6.

Comment: in my above question ename, eno,dept are the comparison fields... but i should check on ename,eno,dept,mgrname,hrname,location,deptid
to return sal and hike fields

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding your question, something like:

```
select a.ename, a.eno, a.dept, b.sal, b.hike
from source a
join ref_table b
    on a.ename = b.ename
    and a.dept = coalesce(b.dept, a.dept)
    and a.eno = coalesce(b.eno, a.eno)
```

Comment: My requirement is  something like , I have source table with some dimention attributes and I need get measure values from ref table based seven common fields... my ref data is going set by user on any of the seven fields,.. some time based on two or three or four (that is  the user choice). so here I need to check not null fields of the ref table data and comapre only those fields with source to get associated measure values.

Comment: I think my solution will do that, add your remaining 5 attributes to the on clause in a similar fashion as the two I included. Coalesce is a function that return it's leftmost non-null value, so if b.dept is null the expression becomes a.dept = a.depth which is a tautology

Comment: a.dept = coalesce(nullif(b.dept,'NA'), a.dept)